# Angular 4: abort all pending $http requests on route change

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a `DataService`, eg.:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getData(): Promise<any[]> {
    return this.http.get('/api/data')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        const js_res = response.json();
        if ( js_res.data ){
          return js_res.data as any[];
        } else {
          throw new Error(js_res.info || response.text); 
        }
      })
      .catch( err => { console.log(err); });
  }
}
```

this `DataService` is called many times in each route. When the user change route, so many request can be pending, and i want abort all pending requests of the old route.

I'm new on Angular 4, what is the right approach?

Comment: `onNgDestroy` unsubscribe from the observable or promise

Comment: @RahulSingh but this is a injectable service, maybe i'm wrong, but it isn't destroyed on route change.

Comment: you will be using this in your component right there you need to unsubscribe , or else go for interceptors

Comment: @RahulSingh google can't help me... you have some example? sorry, i'm a newbie on angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have your Data Service set up and your method `getData()` will make an http request wherever you call it.

Let's say you call this method inside `HeroListComponent`. This component has some life-cycle methods, one of them being `onNgDestroy` which you can use to do your cancellation logic. This method will be automatically called by Angular when you navigate away from this component.

So inside `HeroListComponent` `ngOnInit` method you make the HTTP call and inside the `ngOnDestroy` you unsubscribe from it. I didn't tested the code, but since you transform your Observable into a Promise inside your DataService, I'm not sure you can still unsubscribe. If it doesn't work, you would have to transform the Observable into a Promise only after you save the reference inside the Component `ngOnInit` like `this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getData().toPromise()...`, but still, best practice, try to understand Observables and avoid transforming them into Promises because you lose so much power.

```
class HeroListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getData();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.requestSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```